# Dependent Disjoint Unions in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, discriminated-union

Given a simple `Record<string, Record<string, any>>` defined as a constant record of possible named configurations, **I want a type which dynamically restricts the configuration type based on the key.** Consider the following example:

```
const configs = {
    "fooConfig": {c: "s"},
    "barConfig": {c: 1, b: 2}    
} as const;

type ConfigDef<k extends keyof typeof configs = keyof typeof configs> = {
    a: k,
    v: typeof configs[k]
}

const x: ConfigDef = {
    a: "fooConfig",
    v: {c: 1, b: 2} // this should not work
}
```

Crucially, for the type `ConfigDef`, I need the user to be able to use the type implicitly without passing in the actual key of the config as the generic type (i.e. they should not need to use the explicit syntax `const x: ConfigDef<"fooConfig">`). Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Do you want the type of `configs.fooConfig.c` to be `string` or just `s`? Ditto for the other config, is the type the literal 1 and 2 or `number`?

Comment: You can do this with a generic helper function to infer the generics in ConfigDef for you.

Comment: Do note that `k` is a generic *type* parameter, and as such it is conventionally written uppercase as `K`, to distinguish it from a potential *value* (like a variable named `k`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to refer to `ConfigDef` as a specific (non-generic) type, then it should evaluate to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of your original `ConfigDeg<K>` for each `K` in `keyof typeof configs`.  That is, you need to *distribute* `ConfigDef<K>` across the union `keyof typeof configs`.  One way to do this is to write a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109):

```
type ConfigDef = { [K in keyof typeof configs]: {
    a: K,
    v: typeof configs[K]
} }[keyof typeof configs]
```

That evaluates to

```
/* type ConfigDef = {
    a: "fooConfig";
    v: {
        readonly c: "s";
    };
} | {
    a: "barConfig";
    v: {
        readonly c: 1;
        readonly b: 2;
    };
} */
```

and therefore gives you the behavior you want:

```
const x: ConfigDef = {
    a: "fooConfig",
    v: { c: 1, b: 2 } // error!
}
```

A distributive object type is when you immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  The general form is `{[K in KS]: F<K>}[KS]`, where `KS` is a keylike type.  In your case, we have `KS` being `keyof typeof configs` and `F<K>` as your original `ConfigDef<K>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ssl=4&ssc=12&pln=5&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzCMC8MDeAoAkAEQIggDC4yKhAXDnHYRITAL4A0BhARgIYBOFRKlr1gdAIzsY3OgCY2uVjF7p40ANy5cUAJ4AHAKYwhVACKGEmegG0A0jCRgYAa0O6QVvUc9xKqCABdOjx8Xjo7TnwANzpvQ194Kgh7QKU2GzcPLwMEqySAtNwAegAqGHiTfxQLKyxQ8JhiUlMRLRiQgnx+Q14AE3AAG10GJuZ21i1lAB8cAkaeAVbqdti5-G7egbBh0Yl2zf6hkdkYOQmpmFLi7XVYAA86ZdrrBsYScmrCKLXsPelTgplMVijBDPx+CB+ABCJRAA)